How to improve accuracy when using Paterson-Stockmeyer for polynomial calculating
I'm recently working on the polynomial of matrices (using Paterson-Stockmeyer method) and this paper proposed a mixed precision PS method. Before reproduction I implemented the classical PS (Algorithm 2.1 in this paper) in C++ to test the accuracy. However, when the problem size becomes extra large (e.g. 3 billion x and 15 terms for the polynomial), the cumulative error leads to inaccurate answers ($\epsilon$ = 1e-9). Is there any way to alleviate this problem? Here is my C++ code to implement the PS method.
//Paterson-Stockmeyer
void polynomial(double *polyAns, double *argX, long numX, double coef[], int term)
{
    int m = term-1;
    int s = (int)sqrt((double)m);       

     if(s * s < m)
     {
         s++;    
     }

    int r = (int)(m / s);    

    double *X = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (s+1));

    for(long iter = 0; iter < numX; iter++)
    {
        double ans = 0.0;
        double x = argX[iter];
        X[0] = 1.0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
        {
            X[i] = X[i-1]*x;
        }

        int gNum = s*r;     
        for(int i = 0; i <= m - gNum; i++)
        {
            ans += coef[gNum + i] * X[i];
        }

        for(int i = r-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            double temp_sum = 0.0;
            for(int j = 0; j <= s-1; j++)
            {
                temp_sum += coef[s*i + j] * X[j];
            }
            ans = temp_sum + ans * X[s];
        }

        polyAns[iter] = ans;
    }

    free(X);

}


Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference
